# FRM-40501 unable to reserve record to update

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper, oracleforms

I made a table called groups that has these columns

```
client_id, 
course_name, 
group_number, day
```

the primary key is (client_id, course_name)
so each group number may has many clients
and i want to make a query in my form that displays only the distinct value of group_number and when i update the "day" field it should update day column in all rows with the same group number(for all clients)
so I used from clause query and wrote in it:
**SELECT DISTINCT(GROUP_NUMBER), COURSE_NAME, DAY FROM GROUPS**

when i update this form in run time it gives me this error "unable to reserve record to update" what should I do?

Comment: Can you add some sample data here to make your question more concrete?  You may just be looking for a simple update statement, or possibly something more.

Comment: ok my table has rows in order (client_id, course_name, group_number, day)  like these:

1 , 'database fundamentals' , 1 , 'SAT' ----

2 ,  'database fundamentals' , 1 , 'SAT' ---

3 ,  'database fundamentals' , 1 , 'SAT' ---
1 ,  'database fundamentals-advanced' , 2 , 'SUN' ----
i show in the data block the distinc values of group numbers .. the data in my for is displayed in order of (group_number , course_name , day) like:

1 , 'database fundamentals' , 'SAT' ----

2,  'database fundamentals-advanced'  , 'SUN' ----

and when i update the day of one of them it gives me the error

Comment: is this oracle? mysql? are you linking oracle forms to mysql? im confused

Comment: no, it is only oracle. I deleted mysql tag

Comment: It's been a while since I've worked with Forms.  But if you're using Forms built-ins to update data then in a simple case one row in the form will link to a single row in the database.  In your case you have a one-to-many relationship.  I think you need to use a trigger (ON-UPDATE?) to call some PL/SQL to make the update for you.

Comment: I would also very much recommend you use OAF for all new UI requirements

Answer (score 0):

This issue occurs during the operation where multi-sessions are updating the same row of the same db table.

Let's have a data block named `blk_t1` (table `t1` as "query data source name"). Not only setting "locking mode" of `blk_t1` from "automatic" to "delayed", but also set forms' "isolation mode" to "serializable".

It worked for me for multi-sessioned workaround.